# how can I return an empty object meanwhile the empty object equals to boolean false in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want return an empty object meanwhile the object equals to boolean false in my function.
Obviously,if I return {} like the code below,it equals to boolean true which cannot meet my request.

```
decodeAndParse: function (jsonStr) {
  if (this.NaEptStr(jsonStr)) {
    var result;

    result = decodeURIComponent(jsonStr);
    result = JSON.parse(result);

    return result;
  }
  return false;
}
```

#### Is there any possible to solve this problem?

#### very thankful if anybody can help me solve this problem

Comment: Why not just test for false or an empty object?

Comment: why don't you have a key in `object` and make decisions on that like `if (this.NaEptStr(jsonStr)) { result.status=true; return result}else{return {status:false}}`

Comment: that's really a good way thx. :) @Mritunjay

Comment: if you want this as an answer let me know.

Comment: @Mritunjay—but that requires modifying the returned object and how it is evaluated. There are alternatives that don't require the object to be modified, just how it's evaluated.

Comment: @RobG I think if I got what you are asking, you will be making decision like bellow.

`var result = myFunc(); if(result.status){//code when object is there}else{code of return falses}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code can be:

```
decodeAndParse: function (jsonStr) {
  return this.NaEptStr(jsonStr)? JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(jsonStr)) : {};
}
```

Then in the calling code you probably have something like:

```
var obj = foo.decodeAndParse(jsonStr);

if (obj) {
  ...
}
```

You could have a simple "emptyObj" test like:

```
function isEmptyObject(obj) {
  return !!Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

Then in the caller:

```
if (isEmptyObject(obj)) {
```

If you need to shim Object.keys, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys). Note that IE8 still has a significant user share (greater than 20% of desktop browsers according to [netmarketshare](http://www.netmarketshare.com)) so don't ignore non–ES5 browsers.

Comment: anyone running IE8 must still be running XP, officially EOL :(

Comment: so,an empty object or false,I can only reach one in the last return expression.

Comment: @user2297823–it depends on how the returned value is evaluated, e.g. `if (returnedValue)` will **always** evaluate to *true* if *returnedValue* is an object (even a Boolean object with a value of false) per the rules in [*ECMA-262*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2). You can't change that. So you need to evaluate the returned value differently using one of the methods suggested in the answers (or others).

Answer (score 0):

make a function that counts keys in object

```
function isNotEmpty(obj){
    var count = 0;
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
           ++count;
        }
    }
   return count ? true : false;
}
```

and modify your if to

```
   if (isNotEmpty(this.NaEptStr(jsonStr)))
```

But the simplest way to check if required field in object is present

```
 if(this.naEpStr(jsonStr).myRequiredField)
```

Comment: Yes, of course it is, so long as you're competent enough to use shims to support crappy old MS browsers with ancient JS implementations...

Comment: http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Object.keys
sometimes IE8 is still required =D but you're right

Comment: More to the point, my mantra with JS is to code to modern standards and fix the browsers with shims.  Don't write suboptimal code adhering to old standards.

Comment: There's no need to count the keys, just return true if there are any own properties and false otherwise.

Comment: @RobG that's a fair comment - it would indeed be simpler to just `return true` in the `if` branch.

Comment: so,an empty object or false,I can only reach one in the last return expression?